# Need to create a code for a different username on pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm having a problem on my code every time I put a different username on the username box it print the same schedule. I've been trying to figure out this code but I'm having headache on it. I don't know how to fix it.

windowbox

[image]

```
##!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys 
from PyQt4 import QtGui

global username
username = " "

class Home(QtGui.QWidget):     
    def __init__(self):
        super(Home, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        font   = QtGui.QFont("Times New Roman",10,QtGui.QFont.Bold,False)  #We Changed the font to Times New Roman 

        username = QtGui.QLabel('Username',self)
        username.move(10,40)
        username.setFont(font);

        username = QtGui.QLabel('Enter Courses Prefix',self)
        username.move(10,160)
        username.setFont(font);

        usernameEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        usernameEdit.move(90,35)
        usernameEdit.textChanged[str].connect(self.onChangedusername) #login box for Username
        usernameEdit.setFocus()

        usernameEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        usernameEdit.move(160,160)
        usernameEdit.textChanged[str].connect(self.onChangedusername) #login box for Courses Prefix
        usernameEdit.setFocus()

        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Print all Courses', self)
        btn.move(10, 80)
        btn.setFixedWidth(130)
        btn.setFixedHeight(50)     
        btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: #00FF00") #Print all Courses
        btn.clicked.connect(self.Courses)  
        btn.setFont(font)

        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Print Schedule', self)
        btn.move(180, 80)
        btn.setFixedWidth(130)
        btn.setFixedHeight(50)     
        btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: #00FF00") #Print Schedule
        btn.clicked.connect(self.Schedule)  
        btn.setFont(font)

        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Add Courses', self)
        btn.move(10, 200)
        btn.setFixedWidth(130)
        btn.setFixedHeight(50)     
        btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: #FF00FF") #Add Courses button
        btn.clicked.connect(self.Courses)  
        btn.setFont(font)

        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Drop Courses', self)
        btn.move(180, 200)
        btn.setFixedWidth(130)
        btn.setFixedHeight(50)     
        btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: #FF00FF") #Drop Courses button
        btn.clicked.connect(self.Courses)  
        btn.setFont(font)

        self.setGeometry(5, 30, 600, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('CSCI237 PROJECT')   #Update window title to CSCI237 PROJECT
        self.show()

    def onChangedusername(self, text):
        global username
        username = str(text)

    def Courses(self):
        courses = ["CSCI101, INTRO TO COMPUTER TECHNOLOGY, MORISSON DEIDRA, 10-20, OPEN, MWF 10:00AM-10:50AM MAIN CAMPUS JST, COMPUTER SCIENCE LAB 109, 3, 1-11-2018-04-27-2018"]
        for courses in courses:
            print courses

    def Schedule(self):
        schedules_Ruby = ["CSCI 207 01 UG MC, Mondal Ananda,"]
        print schedules_Ruby

    def Schedule(self):
        schedules_Desmon = ["CSCI 208 01 UG MC,Morisson Diedra,"]
        print schedules_Desmon

    def Schedule(self):
        schedules_Devon = ["CSCI 209 01 UG MC,Dipesh Basnet,"]
        print schedules_Devon

    def Schedule(self):
        schedules_Anna = ["CSCI 210 01 UG MC, Felicia Reid,"]
        print schedules_Anna

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Home()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It is a bad programming practice to have methods with the same name, recommendation: you must use different names.

Comment: how can i fix it?

Comment: when should you return schedules_Devon, when schedules_Anna, etc?

Comment: i have no idea i'm just new on learning python code :(

Comment: everytime i enter a different username it print the same thing.

Comment: How do you have no idea? If you do not have it, I worse, bye, consult your tutor or professor. SO is not a tutoring service.

Comment: You are setting the variable `username`, but then not ever doing anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to rename your methods, it can cause problems using the same name on multiple methods. Adding a number to them should suffice for this purpose.

Secondly, What do you want to happen when you enter a different username? If you want to print the schedule for that student you should look at creating some usernames for those students.

Thirdly, there's actually a newer version of PyQt named PyQt5, while you don't have to upgrade it I highly recommend it :)

Comment: Actually, the second point also applies to your variables, you shouldn't use the same variables multiple times in your code. Clean up your code a little and ill be happy to take a look at it, until then it's to much work for a simple problem.

Comment: i did rename my methods but still print the same schedule and i created usernames for those student :(

Comment: username1 = "ruby"
    username2 = "desmon"
    username3 = "devon"
    username4 = "anna"

Comment: def Schedule (self, student1):
        schedule1 = ["CSCI 207 01 UG MC, Mondal Ananda,"]
        print "Ruby Schedule:"
        print schedule1